# Up to now vs until now

Tags: meaning, time, percentages

I want to say that something is currently completed, in a percentage.

Which sentence is correct?

> Up to now the job has been completed by 10%

or

> Until now the job has been completed by 10%

Thank you in advance

Comment: I would say neither one is correct.  If the job is currently 10% complete, you don't want to preface it with *until now*, etc.  You want to use the present tense and say it is currently 10% complete.

Comment: Ok thanks. Let me extend the example. If I have to justify the 10% do I have to said that up to now we have laded the 10% of the data or until now?

Comment: You don't want to use *until now* because it makes the statement negative; it implies that something has remained the same but then it changed at the current point in time.  Also, can you tell us how formal this needs to be?

Comment: “So far the job is 10% done” or “As of now the job is 10% done.”

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/21690/i-can-t-wait-for-you-until-up-to-8-p-m-one-week

Answer (score 9):

In my (British) English, the only ordinary way of saying this is *so far*.

The phrases *up to now* and *until now* are slightly stilted, and if they were used by a native English speaker I would infer some special meaning, that something significant has changed or is about to change. Perhaps that the way of measuring the amount is different, or that the job is getting much harder.

Answer (score 2):

Up to - used for various points and measures to describe a certain segment (not necessarily time. E.g. fill the container up to 500 ml mark)

Until/till - used to describe a lapse of time before a certain point in time (E.g. we waited until sunset - i.e. waiting is the lapse between *now* and *sunset*)

For your example sentence, I would suggest:

> - **Currently/at the moment**, the job has been completed *up to*/by 10%.
> - 10% of the job has been completed **so far**.

It seems that rather than a period of time, your sentence alludes to reporting the status at a precise point in time, which is present/now.

Answer (score 1):

My belief is this: Unless something is against grammar or long-held idiom, all is good, as long as the meaning is clear.

The two sentences above make sense to me. Since I am no grammarian, I don't know if it goes against any established rules.

If it were I, I should more likely say, "As of now, 10% of the job is completed".